# Listar diretórios e arquivos PHP

Tags: php, lista, arquivo, diretório

Olá, tenho um código PHP que funciona bem para o que foi proposto, porém preciso de alguns ajustes nele. 
O código em questão já me lista os diretórios e os arquivos, porem em diretórios que eu tenha arquivos e subdiretórios ele me lista embaralhados.
Gostaria que o código fizesse a separação do que é arquivo e do que é diretório, mostrando os diretórios no inicio da lista, e os aquivos depois. 
Caso seja possível depois da separação, listar também por ordem alfabética dentro do seu tipo. 
Exemplo de saída esperado:

Abelha/
Boatos/
Coalha/
abelhass.png
boatos.png
coalhass.png

Meu conhecimento em PHP é praticamente nulo, porém foi a melhor alternativa que encontrei.
Se alguém puder me ajudar na adaptação do código, agradeço bastante;

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title class="title h1"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fondamento|Hanuman|Kaushan+Script|Nanum+Pen+Script|Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .bg-grey{
        background-color: #E6E6E6;
    }
    .bg-azulClarrisimo{
        background-color: #E0F2F7;
    }
    .title{
        font-family: 'Fondamento', cursive;
    }
    .comfortaa{
        font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {

      .tamanho{
        font-size: 10px;
      }
    }

</style>
<body>
    <?php
      //diretorio
        $baseDir = './';
        $abreDir = (array_key_exists('dir', $_GET) ? $_GET['dir'] : $baseDir);
        $openDir = dir($abreDir);

        $strrdir = strrpos(substr($abreDir,0,-1),'/');

        $backDir = substr($abreDir,0,$strrdir+1);                                       


        if($abreDir != $baseDir){
            echo '<a class="btn btn-warning " href="index.php?dir='.$backDir.'"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Voltar</a>';
        }
        echo '<hr>';
        echo '<table class="text-left table table-dark reponsive tamanho" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellspadding="">';                 
        while($arq = $openDir -> read()): 
            if($arq != '.' && $arq != '..' &&  $arq != 'index.php'):                
                if(is_dir($abreDir.$arq)){
                //pastas                                                        
                    echo '<tr>';    
                    echo '<td class="alert alert-info text-left tamanho"><a class="form-control btn text-left tamanho" href="index.php?dir='.$abreDir.$arq.'/"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'.$arq.'</a></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';    
                }else{
                //arquivos
                    echo '<tr>';                                                            
                    echo '<td class="alert text-right tamanho"><a class="form-control btn text-white text-right tamanho" href="'.$abreDir.$arq.'" target="_blank">'.$arq.' &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <i class="fa fa-download" ></i></a></td>';  
                    echo '</tr>';                                
                }                    
            endif;              
        endwhile;
        echo '</table>';
        echo '<hr>';
        if($abreDir != $baseDir){
            echo '<a class="btn btn-warning" href="index.php?dir='. $backDir.'"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Voltar</a>';
        }                                       

    ?>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

acho que isso resolve seu problema:

```
<?php
    $itens = new DirectoryIterator('./');
    foreach($itens as $item){
        if($item->gettype() === 'dir'){
            $diretorios[] = $item->getFilename();
        }else{
            $arquivos[] = $item->getFilename();
        }

    }


    foreach($diretorios as $diretorio){
        echo '<tr>';    
        echo '<td class="alert alert-info text-left tamanho">'.$diretorio.'</td>';
        echo '</tr><br>';
    }

    foreach($arquivos as $arquivo){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="alert text-right tamanho">'.$arquivo.'</td>';
        echo '</tr><br>';
    }?>
```

o DirectoryIterator vai varrer o diretório e o primeiro foreach vai iterar sobre os itens o if irá separar em arrays os diretorios dos arquivos e o segundo foreach vai iterar sobre o arrey dos diretórios e o terceiro fará o mesmo sobre os arquivos.

Uma forma de linkar os subdiretórios sem precisar usar vários arquivos .php seria armazenando em uma variável o diretório que você deseja listar o conteúdo e passar via get esse parametro.

```
<?php
$dir = isset($_GET['dir']) ? './'.$_GET['dir']: './';

$itens = new DirectoryIterator("$dir");
   foreach($itens as $item){
    if($item->gettype() === 'dir'){
        $diretorios[] = $item->getFilename();
    }else{
        $arquivos[] = $item->getFilename();
    }

}


foreach($diretorios as $diretorio){
    echo '<tr>';    
    echo '<td class="alert alert-info text-left tamanho"><a href="?dir='.$diretorio.'">/'.$diretorio.'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr><br>';
}

foreach($arquivos as $arquivo){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="alert text-right tamanho"><a href="/'.$arquivo.'">'.$arquivo.'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr><br>';
}?>
```

caso queira bloquear o acesso direto aos diretórios você pode usar .htaccess e melhorar usando urls amigáveis, dá uma olhada pelo google e aqui no stack também, tem muito assunto sobre isso

Comment: Eu sei que é pedir muito, mas poderia me ajudar a adaptar o seu código ao meu? Meu conhecimento em PHP é nulo.  O seu código funciona bem, porém só funciona no diretório inicial.  Uma solução que encontrei usando seu código foi colocar um arquivo index.php em cada diretório e sub-diretório. Porém é bem amadora e nada pratica e funcional.

Comment: dá uma olhada que editei a resposta incluindo algo que deve ajudar.